# FileSystemWatcher Windows is unable to stop the device ‘USB Mass storage Device'

Tags: c#

I have created a service in C# that will start a `FileSystemWatcher` when a USB drive in plugged in to the computer.

It tracks new directories created and files that are copied to the USB drive. It works great, the only problem is when you click on Safely remove hardware and Eject media, you get the message that Windows is unable to stop the device 'USB Mass storage Device'.

Is there a way I can stop the the `FileSystemWatcher` when someone click on Safely remove hardware and Eject media?

Code:

```
namespace USB_Drive2
{
public class FileWatcher
{
    private string Directory { get; set; }
    private string Filter { get; set; }

    private string _fromDir;

    FileSystemWatcher fileW = new FileSystemWatcher();

    public FileWatcher()
    {

    }

    public FileWatcher(string directory, string filter, string serverDIR)
    {
        this._fromDir = serverDIR;
        this.Directory = directory;
        this.Filter = filter;
    }

    public void StartFileWatcher()
    {
        fileW.Filter = this.Filter;
        fileW.Path = this.Directory;
        fileW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fileW.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        fileW.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(onChanged);
        fileW.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(onReNamed);
    }

    public void StopFileWatcher()
    {
        fileW.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        fileW.Dispose();
    }

    private void onReNamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        //var USBW1 = new FileWatcher(e.FullPath, "*.*", "a");
        //USBW1.StartFileWatcher();
    }

    private void onChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        //string _combined;
        string _localCombined;
        string _timeOfDay;
        DateTime loacalDate = DateTime.Now;
        _timeOfDay = loacalDate.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        _timeOfDay = _timeOfDay.Replace(":", "");
        _timeOfDay = _timeOfDay.Replace(".", "");
        _timeOfDay = _timeOfDay.Remove(6);
        _localCombined = loacalDate.Year.ToString() + loacalDate.DayOfYear.ToString() + _timeOfDay;

        //************************************************************************************************
        FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);

        if ((fi1.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory {0} Created on {1} {2}", e.FullPath, fi1.CreationTime.Date.ToShortDateString(), fi1.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} Created on {1} {2}", e.FullPath, fi1.CreationTime.Date.ToShortDateString(), fi1.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
        }
        //************************************************************************************************

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You will get a better response to your questions if you provide some code.  In many cases someone has solution but will need to prototype it to make sure.  Providing some sample code make this process a lot easier.

Comment: This guy tackled the same problem: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32026/Capturing-Device-Events-in-a-C-Windows-Service ...(looks like it's a big hassle to do it in a Windows service)

Comment: After many hours of reading and trying different solutions I have finally got this working.
I will write more soon.

Comment: can you please post your solution